# How to show categorized Highcharts Chart using csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I'm trying to show a `Chart` with `Highcharts`, using `javascript`.

I've read the `csv` file using `Highcharts` `modules/data.js` and the `Chart` is showing without problems inside my container.
[image]

```
mychart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  data: {
    csv: csv,
    startColumn:0,
    endColumn:2
  },
  title: {
    text: 'DATA'
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'X'
     },
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Y'
    }
  }
});
```

Basically the csv have 3 columns, with commas separating attributes and break lines for each row.

```
x, y, category
data1, data2, data3
data1, data2, data3
data1, data2, data3
data1, data2, data3
data1, data2, data3
...
```

The first and the seconds columns are the points coordinates and the third is the category. I want to display points based on one of the categories in the third row.

I don't know how to show all `x` & `y` points categorized by `category` column.

Comment: A scatter point has only two values - x and y coordinates. Can you explain what the third value represents and how it should be drawn on the chart?

Comment: x and y are the scatter points, the third column is the category of the scatter points, a number between 0 and 6. The Chart should be displayed in 6 different colors where the scatter points are grouped.

Comment: Well, thinking a bit round about but...Why not parse the CSV outside of highcharts data.js and then, depending on the category value assign a color to your point like `{x: theXvalue, y: theYvalue, color: 'somecolor'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a category as a series in Highcharts. So you need to create an array like this

```
series: [{
  name: 'Series ' + categoryNumber,
  data: [] // array with x and y coordinates
}, {
  name: ''
  data: []
}]
```

Then you can parse your csv file, it would be easier without data module.

```
var rows = csv.split('\n');

var series = [];
rows.forEach(row => {
  var cells = row.split(',').map(Number);
  var serie = series[cells[2]];

  if (!serie) {
    serie = series[cells[2]] = {data: []};
  }

  serie.data.push([cells[0], cells[1]]);
})

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter'
  },

  series: series

});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/w7ug4dbw/

There is important for the chart series that you will not have gaps in your category - so if you have categories 0 - 2, you need to have data for all 0,1,2 category - if you don't, then you can receive the errors while using the chart. To overcome that, you would need to loop through the series array and delete all the gaps.